# MongoDB lte and gte not works in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to get the in between records using date field with the combination of mongo and GoLang, I tried many way but I can't able to get the records. Same query works well in Robo3T.

MongoDB date format - ISODate("2023-03-20T13:30:24Z")

Sample Mongo Query

```
db.getCollection('userDetails').find({
        "status":{"$in":["CREATED", "APPROVED"]},
        "type": {"$in":["employee", "guest"]},
        "endDate": {"$gte": ISODate("2023-03-15T00:00:00Z"),"$lte": ISODate("2023-03-20T23:59:59Z")},
        "roles": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "agencyDetails.userDetails.userName": "EMP123",
                "agencyDetails.userDetails.status": {"$in":["PENDING", "ACCEPTED"]},
                "agencyDetails.userDetails.inTime": {"$exists":false}
             }
        }
        })
```

Go Format

```
findQuery := bson.M{
    "status": bson.M{"$in": []string{constant.CREATED, constant.APPROVED}},
    "type":   bson.M{"$in": []string{constant.EMP, constant.GUEST}},
    "endDate": bson.M{"$gte": today, "$lte": fiveDayStr},
    "roles": bson.M{"$elemMatch": 
        bson.M{
            "agencyDetails.userDetails.userName": userName,
            "agencyDetails.userDetails.status": bson.M{"$in": []string{constant.PENDING, constant.ACCEPTED}},
            "agencyDetails.userDetails.inTime": bson.M{"$exists": false},
        },
    },
}

err = rs.DB().C(collectionName).Find(findQuery).Sort("-endDate").All(&users)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err

}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Have you tried [primitive.DateTime](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.3/bson/primitive#DateTime)? That is to replace `today` with `primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().UTC().Truncate(24 * time.Hour))` (and `fiveDayStr`).

Comment: I think a value of type `time.Time` should work because the doc states that `time.Time marshals to a BSON datetime.` (see https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson@v1.11.3). So try `time.Now().UTC().Truncate(24 * time.Hour)` first.